# Enter variable in html block: Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input inside an html block and I insert this html block in javascript. The result is to see this block in the 'Demonstration' html place I first created. The problem I face is that I cannot pass the vValue variable in the html block. That is, I get "${vValue}" instead of "123". Is it something like that possible ? **The interesting thing here is that I can get the input but I cannot enter a variable in input**, and this is why I pose the question. Thank you very much all of you.

```html
<div id="Demostration"></div>

    <script>
        vValue = '123'
    </script>

    <script id="Block" type="text/html">
        <form  id = "FormID">
            <input type="text" id="InputID" value=${vValue}>
        </form>
    </script>
    
    <script>
            vBlock = document.getElementById('Block').innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('Demostration').innerHTML = vBlock;
    </script>
```

Comment: This is typically the syntax used by a templating framework. But there is no such magic in vanilla JavaScript. `${vValue}` is just text like any other text.

Comment: It is pure javascript

Comment: I know, that's what I am saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use template literals (ie ` backticks) wrapping the HTML it will work.

```js
  vValue = '123'

  form = `<form  id = "FormID"><input type="text" id="InputID" value='${vValue}'></form>`;

  document.getElementById('Demostration').innerHTML = form;
```

```html
<div id="Demostration"></div>
```

Comment: I could never have thought of that !!! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="Demostration"></div>

    <script>
        vValue = '123'
    </script>

    <form  id = "FormID">
        <input type="text" id="InputID" value=`${vValue}`>
    </form>
    <script>
            document.getElementById('InputID').value = vValue
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 <div id="Demostration"></div>

<script>`enter code here`
    vValue = '123'
</script>

<script id="Block">
function getContent(){
return "<form id = 'FormID'>  <input type='text' id='InputID' value='" + vValue + "''></form>"
}
</script>

<script>
        
        document.getElementById('Demostration').innerHTML = getContent();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not automatically replaced when accessing or assigning the `innerHTML` property. You can use the `replace()` function to do it explicitly.

```js
let vValue = '123'
let vBlock = document.getElementById('Block').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('Demostration').innerHTML = vBlock.replace('${vValue}', vValue);
```

```html
<div id="Demostration"></div>
<template id="Block">
  <form id="FormID">
    <input type="text" id="InputID" value=${vValue}>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to put backticks on the temlate literal

```
 <input type="text" id="InputID" value=`${vValue}`>
```

Comment: Backticks are JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Barmar you are right. I rushed to answer and didnt look into the code properly.